# use reactivePoll to monitor the change of folder

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to shiny, and trying to make a folder monitor based on @jdharrison 's reply at
[Use reactivePoll to accumulate data for output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23448638/6911037)

The f1, or check function, seems like a validator. Once it gives whatever results, it triggers the f2, the true action-taker. Then, we render the output.

As the toy sample runs, the f1 does creates files,  but not producing the result of listing all the files, as expected.

by the way, the code is running on ubuntu, and the files are saved in a sub-directory called `temp`

Where did I go wrong?

Would like to invite your advice.

```
runApp(
  list(
    ui =
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput("DT")
      ),
    server =
      function(input, output, session) {
        # f1 as a tempfile creater. Once it is called. it creates a txt
        f1 <- function() system(paste0("touch ", tempfile(tmpdir = "./temp", fileext = "txt")))

        # f2 list all the files
        f2 <- function(){
          list.files("temp", full.names = T) 
        }
        data <- reactivePoll(5000, session, f1, f2)
        output$DT <- renderTable(data())
      }
  )
)
```

Thanks to suggection from @TonioLiebrand. The f1, check function, is exactly what it is, a checking function.

After I change the return of f1, it works.
I will keep the post here maybe it might help someone someday.

```
runApp(
  list(
    ui =
      mainPanel(
        DTOutput("DT")
      ),
    server =
      function(input, output, session) {
        f1 <- function() {
          system(paste0("touch ", tempfile(tmpdir = "./temp", fileext = "txt")))
          file.info(list.files("temp", full.names = T))["mtime"]
        }
        f2 <- function(){
          list.files("temp", full.names = T) %>% as.matrix()
        }
        
        data <- reactivePoll(5000, session, f1, f2) 
        
        output$DT <- renderDT({datatable(data())})
      }
  )
)
```

Comment: In the docu of `reactivePoll`, `checkFunc` is described as  
`A relatively cheap function whose values over time will be tested for equality;`. So it monitors e.g. the timestamp of a file. You use it to create new files,...

Comment: Thanks @TonioLiebrand, can I see it in this way? it triggers `value function` once it notices the diffence?

Comment: That would be my understanding, yes. But what is your actual goal. List all files and update the view, if a new file is added?

Comment: @TonioLiebrand, thanks for the hint. You are correct! it works bcs of your suggection. pls find my update.